# Using jQuery in Mocha tests with Node NOT io.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, mocha.js, jsdom

I'm running Mocha/Chai unit tests of a module which uses jQuery (for ajax calls) and of course jQuery complains about the missing document, cause I run tests without browser. I found jsdom module which creates virtual dom, that can fool jquery, but the project has ditched node.js in favor of io.js and can't be used with node. I don't think I feel like switching to io.js in the middle of a project so my question is:

Is there any sane way of using jQuery in Mocha tests from commandline at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

Node can make its own HTTP requests with a built-in `http` module. You don't need jQuery. There is also the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module which is very nice and probably quite a few others.

Your options are:

1. Don't use jQuery
2. Switch to iojs anyway (or [`node 4`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/))
3. Install an older version (earlier than version 4) of jsdom that will still allow you to use older versions of node

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I'm writing a webapp using browserify modules and jQuery is used in the tested module so I'd like to stay with jQuery for now. Node 4 came out 3 days ago, so it's just asking for trouble and installing jsdom 3.x.x fails on rebuilding node-gyp. Howerver, shouldn't running tests in browser (or phantom browser) solve the jQuery problem as well?

Comment: @konrad the _stable_ version of node 4 was released recently. There have been release candidates for node 4 for some time before that.

Comment: allright, but doesn't a major version bump mean there are some breaking changes and that the npm ecosystem might not be wholly up to date? Probably I should just use n or nvm to check but as a matter of fact I'm getting a bit weary of reconfiguring stuff to get a simple thing done. :-) Thanks anyway, probably in a couple of months your answer will be the only sensibly one.

Comment: @konrad yes there are _breaking changes_ but you can read through the changelogs to see what they are and test our your code in new versions. I'm pretty sure they won't affect you actually.